# I want to change the record type of contact if 6 months has passed since 'last communication date'

Tags: workflow, record-type, field-update, time-dependent-workflow

i have written a workflow rule that will Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria, which eventually will change record type of contact.

Rule Criteria:

```
AND(
    TODAY() - Date_of_Last_Communication__c = 180,
    RecordType.Name = 'Volunteer',
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c , "Inactive"),
    ISPICKVAL( Sub_Status__c , "Inquiry")
)
```

However, what if 6 months has past from last communication date and record has not been edited even once since? will the workflow still trigger? if not any other solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Workflow rules only fire when records are created or edited. Assuming that Date of Last Communication is not a formula (e.g. it contains real data), you can set your workflow rule criteria as:

```
RecordType.Name = 'Volunteer' && 
ISPICKVAL(Status__c , "Inactive") && 
ISPICKVAL( Sub_Status__c , "Inquiry")
```

Then set a Time Based Workflow action that triggers 180 days after Date of Last Communication. Consider reading the [Time-Based Workflow FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245) and [Considerations for Time-Dependent Actions and Time Triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&language=en).